# How to change the visibility style using the ternary operator (Typescript)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How do I change the same code to `display:block` and `display:none`? Is it like this?

```
[style.visibility] = "anyVariable ? 'block' : 'none'">
```

If `anyVariable` is true, then `block`, if false, then `none`, right?

I'm using typescript and angular

Comment: `[style.visibility]="anyVariable?'visible':'hidden'"`. To change the style you can use [style.property]="variable", (variable can be an expresion too). You can also use [ngStyle]="variable" where variable is an object

Answer (score 0):

`block` & `none` are the `display` css attribute variables.
So you should use `display` css attribute.

```
[style.display] = "anyVariable ? 'block' : 'none'">
```

or you can use `ngStyle` for this.

```
[ngStyle]="{'display': anyVariable ? 'block' : 'none' }"
```